# How Can Mark Product Featured WooCommerce using php code

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce

I want mark product featured by id using code

i tried this code but not working

```
// Your Product ID
$product_id   = 43706;
$ecd_product  = new WC_Product( $product_id );
if( $ecd_product->exists() ){
    $ecd_product->set_featured( true );
    $ecd_product->save();
}
```

and tried this not working

```
$product_id   = 43706;
$ecd_product  = new WC_Product( $product_id );
if( $ecd_product->exists() ){
    update_post_meta( $ecd_product->id, '_featured', 'yes' );
}
```

Comment: https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/classes/WC-Product.html#method___construct says, _"This class should NOT be instantiated, but the wc_get_product() function should be used. It is possible, but the wc_get_product() is preferred."_ - so I'd try that first of all.

Comment: Also, it has not only a `save` method, but also `save_meta_data`. Maybe you need to use the latter for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above code snippet is correct -

```
function modify_wc_products_callback() {
    // Your Product ID
    $product_id   = 43706;
    $ecd_product  = new WC_Product( $product_id );
   
    if( $ecd_product->exists() ) {
        $ecd_product->set_featured( true );
        $ecd_product->save();
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'modify_wc_products_callback' );
```

And it should work perfectly to make product as featured. But in your case I'm guessing that you are calling this snippet in wrong places, hooks or before initializing WC product class functionalities.
Please share your exact codebase in order to help further.